# Artifactory composer packages.json 404

Tags: composer-php, artifactory

I am using artifactory and have no issues with the npm solution. However, I have set up composer using the "Set Me Up" instructions, i.e. installed the `~/.composer/config.json` & `~/.composer/auth.json` files. I now get the following error when I try to perform a composer install:

```
$ dcomp install
Loading composer repositories with package information


[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
The "https://myartifactory.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/composer/php-local/packages.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)


install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] ...
```

The user I have configured in `auth.json` is an admin user, and I've pushed a single package into the Artifactory. Additionally, I noticed the url contains plural `packages.json` as opposed to singular `package.json`, so I am assuming this is an issue with the artifactory configuration itself and not the package I've uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in my case was as a couple commenters observed: the index wasn't being generated.

For me, the fix was a matter of using a `.zip` compressed file to upload composer packages instead of a `.tar.gz`. I can't tell you why a tarball won't work, especially considering Artifactory's documentation explicitly mentions `tar.gz`, but it would appear `.zip` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

For Artifactory to index composer packages successfully you also need to make sure that each package has version specified.

There are 3 ways to achieve that:

1. Include the version attribute in the package composer.json file
2. Set a composer.version property on the package itself.
3. Use the version field when deploying it via the UI.

You can easily test it inside the UI by clicking on the archive you just uploaded, then go to the properties tab and add a property for example:

composer.version with value for example 1.0.0.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have confirmed the package I've uploaded does indeed have a `composer.version` attribute in artifactory's UI.

Answer (score 0):

When you first create a PHP composer repository in Artifactory it will not have the repository index yet (package.json file). The index will be created only after you deploy your first package.
It is possible that Artifactory was unable to read the package metadata for the package you deployed. In such a case, assuming this is the only package in the repository, the index will not be calculated.
In order to verify this is the case:

1. Browse the `php-local` repository in the Artifactory UI
2. Check for the presence of a `.composer/packages.json` file (relative to the repository root). If it does not exist, it is an indication that Artifactory was unable to calculate the repository index
3. Select the package you deployed, and switch to the Composer Info tab
4. Check that you can see the correct package version. If you see "No version found" - there was an issue with getting the version (probably because it is not included in the `composer.json` file)
5. Look for an error similar to the following in the artifactory log file:

> Failed to persist package metadata for 'php-local/my-package.zip'.
> Unable to read the package version from the extracted composer.json
> file

If this is the case, you can solve the issue by:

1. Add a property named `composer.version` to your composer package and set its value to be the correct package version. You can do it by selecting the package file from the UI, switching to the Properties tab and adding a new property
2. If this done correctly you should be able to see the correct version in the Composer Info tab and that the `packages.json` file is being generated

If all of this does not help and the packages.json file is still not generated, there is probably another error which prevents Artifactory from generating it.

Try re-generating the repository index by:

1. Going to the root of the repository in the Artifactory UI
2. Right click the root of the repository and choose "Recalculate Index"
   [image]
3. The index should be generated in the background
4. If the index is still not generated search the artifactory log file for any relevant error messages

Finally, one more option to try is deploying a different composer package and seeing if it behaves the same.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. I was able to get in touch with artifactory support and they suggested trying a .zip file -- whereas I had been using a tarball. That seemed to allow the index to properly generate and I'm up and running now.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen an Include / Exclude Pattern on the Jfrog repository that does not match the `<vendor>/<package>` naming standard cause this issue. We were able to  upload artifacts but they were excluded metadata endpoint.

The following endpoint returned a 404 response code for every package until the Include / Exclude Pattern was fixed.

```
https://<org>.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/composer/<repo>/p2/<vendor>/<package>.json
```